# Search for exact values in elasticsearch returns to many results

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am using the following request with the official elasticsearch-php client.

```
  private function getAllStatisticsByDomain() {
    $params = [
      'index' => 'stats',
      'type' => 'domain_stats',
      'size' => 99,
      'body' => [
        'query' => [
          'match' => [
            'domain' => 'http://veehouder.cono.nl',
          ],
        ],
      ],
    ];

    $response = $this->getElasticClient()->search($params);


    return $response['hits']['hits'];
  }
```

The first 4 results all have the field domain => http://veehouder.cono.nl but it also retrieves more results which does not have the value "http://veehouder.cono.nl"(see screenshot).

I also have a function where this request is working fine, but is in on a date field.

```
  private function getAllStatisticsByDay() {
    $params = [
      'index' => 'stats',
      'type' => 'domain_stats',
      'size' => 99,
      'body' => [
        'query' => [
          'match' => [
            'date' => date('Y-m-d'),
          ],
        ],
      ],
    ];

    $response = $this->getElasticClient()->search($params);


    return $response['hits']['hits'];
  }
```

Can somebody please explain me why the function getAllStatisticsByDomain() retrieves more results then i want?[image]

This is my index function :

```
/**
 * @param $id
 * @param $domain
 * @param $googlePSMobileScore
 * @param $googlePSMobileUsabilityScore
 * @param $googlePSDesktopScore
 * @param $mozPDA
 * @param $mozUPA
 */
function insert($id, $domain, $googlePSMobileScore, $googlePSMobileUsabilityScore, $googlePSDesktopScore, $mozPDA, $mozUPA, $date) {
  $params = [
    'index' => 'stats',
    'type' => 'domain_stats',
    'id' => $id,
    'body' => [
      'domain' => $domain,
      'googlePSMobileScore' => $googlePSMobileScore,
      'googlePSMobileUsabilityScore' => $googlePSMobileUsabilityScore,
      'googlePSDesktopScore' => $googlePSDesktopScore,
      'mozPDA' => $mozPDA,
      'mozUPA' => $mozUPA,
      'date' => $date,
    ],
  ];

  getElasticClient()->index($params);
}
```

My mapping of the fields :

```
{
    "stats": {
        "mappings": {
            "domain_stats": {
                "properties": {
                    "date": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
                    },
                    "domain": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "googlePSDesktopScore": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "googlePSMobileScore": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "googlePSMobileUsabilityScore": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "mozPDA": {
                        "type": "double"
                    },
                    "mozUPA": {
                        "type": "double"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use `term` instead of `match`

Comment: What do you get when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200/stats/domain_stats/_mapping` ?

Comment: Hi Val! I updated my question with the mapping i get back from curl -XGET localhost:9200/stats/domain_stats/_mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `domain` field is an analyzed string, it should be not analyzed. You need to delete your index and recreate it with the following mapping:

```
                "domain": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
```

Then you need to reindex your data and query it like this and it will work:

```
  'body' => [
    'query' => [
      'term' => [
        'domain' => 'http://veehouder.cono.nl',
      ],
    ],
  ],
```